# How to make a div centered and all sides be equidistant from wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper that takes up the whole screen and I want to make another div to be centered inside it and all its sides be equidistant from the wrapper.

css:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
}
#inner_div {
    /*centered, sides equidistant from wrapper*/
}
```

Comment: This is not a good example because if your wrapper is 100% height/div, it means it needs another wrapper div with fixed height/div to work.

Comment: Define equidistant? What spacing is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
.a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```